# xcode update from 4.5.1 to 4.6

Tags: xcode, xcode4, updates

Hi I am new to Xcode and wondering how do I perform an update from v4.5.1 to v4.6. Is it necessary to uninstall the current xcode on my Mac in order to upgrade my xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to uninstall the actual version of Xcode. Just open the Mac App Store and an update will appear on the "Updates" tab for Xcode. Have fun!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Please accept this question by clicking on the "tick" icon positioned on the left of this answer! Thank you!

Comment: I tried this for 4.5.2 to 4.6.2, but it only showed Install App for Xcode, not update.

Answer (score 0):

Click the mac App Store icon.  When you launch the app store, you should see software updates needed.  Click on software updates and find xcode.  Simply click on it to update it.  No need to uninstall your current version.