# No member named 'bind" in the namespace of std error

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4

The following codes can run very well in WINDOWS and LINUX but fail in MAC:

```
template <typename T>
inline bool similar_fun(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &B, T threshold)
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    std::vector<T> differ;
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
        std::back_inserter(differ), std::bind(sub_fun<T>, _1, _2));

    return (std::accumulate(differ.begin(), differ.end(), static_cast<T>(0), Norm2<T>()) <= threshold);
}
```

The development platform is Xcode 4, and the compiler is Clang LLVM 1.0. I also make sure that the compiler is using the new C++ standard c++0x. The error messages are as follows:

```
   using namespace std::placeholders; *Expect namespace name
std::bind(sub_fun) *No member named "bind" in namespace std
```

Comment: Did you explicitly include `<functional>`? Sometimes headers get implicitly included in some platforms, but not in others.

Comment: @Arne Meritz Thanks, I have already put the head file.

Comment: LLVM 1.0?  Are you sure?  This compiler [is dated](http://llvm.org/releases/) 24 Oct 2003.

Comment: @JohnDibling just went to the realease site and noticed it's pretty old. I guess it's just an old standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang LLVM 1.0 seems pretty old, it's from 2003, so the standard library you have installed probably is a C++03 standard library that does not have `placeholders` and `bind`. You could try to include new C++11 headers, e.g. `<array>` to confirm that.

If I am right, just update your compiler :-)

Comment: Thanks, and could you let me know how to update the compiler? You are right and I cannot compile if <array> head file is included.

Comment: Uhm, I honeslty have no experience with XCode, LLVM and MAC. But a quick googling told me the updating xcode should be possible from the app store: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823519/xcode-update-from-4-5-1-to-4-6

Comment: There are also possibilities of getting more recent versions of Clang than the one included in the latest XCode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674546/how-to-update-llvm-clang-on-mac-osx